# Random left, top position, jquery, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of div elements, which is dragable items.

I need to do, that all elements, i will generate random top and left positions, which will be in range of my container, but i dont know how to do it :)

Container div is: width: 800px; height: 500px;

My js now is like:

```
var randomTopPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (600 / 2));
var randomLeftPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5));

$(".t-shirt-design").css({
    'top' : randomTopPos,
    'left': randomLeftPos
});
```

Comment: what is the height of the draggable items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given than your container id is `container` and your draggable id is `dragid`, you can do as follows:

```
ctop = $('#container').offset().top;  // container top
cleft = $('#container').offset().left;// container left
cheight = $('#container').height();   // container height
cwidth = $('#container').width();     // container width

$(".t-shirt-design").each(function() {
   dragheight = $(this).height(); //your draggable height
   dragwidth  = $(this).width(); // your draggable width
   randomtop = ctop + Math.floor((Math.random()* (cheight - dragheight))+1);
   randomleft = cleft + Math.floor((Math.random()* (cwidth - dragwidth))+1);
   $(this).css({
     'top' : randomtop,
     'left': randomleft
   });
});
```

**UPDATE**:
Updated the code to accomodate several `.t-shirt-design` elements

**UPDATE 2**:
Also you have an error in your html code, an html element can only have ONE id, you have two in your container html element, as follows:

```
<div id="tshirts-designs homepage">
```

replace it for just one, the correct would be:

```
<div id="homepage">
```

**UPDATE 3**:
Looking at your page, I adjust my code to better fit your requirements (your draggable elements have different widths and heights), so try my update code instead, also better execute this code on the `window.load` event, instead of `.ready` , as we need the images to be loaded so the div heights and widths are the correct ones, so replace your following line:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

for this one:

```
$(window).load(function() {
```

Comment: I dont know, what i do wrong. Here is my link: http://jurciukonis.lt/wordpress/T-Land/ I have paste all code, change class'es, but... It doesnt work:/

Comment: So you have several ".t-shirt-design" elements, I updated my answer to handle that, try the new code.

Comment: Oh, thanks, it almost perfect, but i need 1 more corection ;) Some of elements, can be over of second element, i mean, that element which is first, in first line, on this element, can be the second line last item. Top and left positionsecond line can be 20 or 30 px litle, that is now (Sorry for my english, i dont know, meyby u understand ;))

Comment: See my UPDATE 3 above, I change the code again, try the new one.

Comment: Now itisperfect. Thanks Nelson!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".t-shirt-design").each(function(){
   var $t = $(this);
   var randomTopPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (containerHeight-$t.width()));
   var randomLeftPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (containerWidth-$t.height()));
   $t.css({
      'top': randomTopPos,
      'left':randomLeftPos
   });
});
```

Replace `containerHeight` and `containerWidth` with their real values. Make sure the items are inside the container and have `position:relative;`

Comment: Okey, i have just try it, but my all item is different size ;) its images?;)

Comment: @Jurciukonis: I've edited my answer, it should work for different sizes now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var randomTopPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (600 / 2));
var randomLeftPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5));

$(".t-shirt-design").css({
    'top' : Math.floor(Math.random() * $(this).parent().height() - itemHeight),
    'left': Math.floor(Math.random() * $(this).parent().width() - itemWidth) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're on the right path...

`Math.random()` is generating numbers between 0 and 1.

You multiply these numbers by the range you want, changing the range to 0-range.

You then assign these values as top/left positions.

Some considerations:

1. What are the widths and heights of the elements? If they vary, you may need to generate each position based on the given object's width/height. Otherwise, factor them in as a constant. If you have 50x50px items your max 'top' is 450 and max 'left' is 750, so multiply by 450 and 750 instead of 500 and 800.
2. You're applying these values to a CSS class, which, if you've assigned the same class to every item, will not randomize them but put them in the same place. You may wish to do something like:

   ```
   $(".t-shirt-design").each(function(e){
       // Generate random numbers
       e.css({
           'top' : randomTopPos,
           'left': randomLeftPos
       });
   });
   ```